# Return count for specific value in pandas .value_counts()?

Tags: pandas

Assume running pandas' dataframe['prod_code'].value_counts() and storing result as 'df'.  The operation outputs:

```
125011  90300
   762  72816
  None  55512
  7156  14892 
 75162   8825
```

How would I extract the count for None?  I'd expect the result to be 55512.

I've tried

```
>>> df.loc[df.index.isin(['None'])]
>>> Series([], Name: prod_code, dtype: int64)
```

and also

```
>>> df.loc['None']
>>> KeyError: 'the label [None] is not in the [index]'
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need `None`, not string `'None'`:

```
df.loc[df.index.isin([None])]

df.loc[None]
```

EDIT:

If need check where `NaN` in index:

```
print (s1.loc[np.nan])
#or
print (df[pd.isnull(df.index)])
```

Sample:

```
s = pd.Series(['90300', '90300', '8825', '8825', '8825', None, np.nan])
s1 = s.value_counts(dropna=False)
print (s1)
8825     3
90300    2
NaN      2
dtype: int64

print (s1[pd.isnull(s1.index)])
NaN    2
dtype: int64
```

---

```
print (s1.loc[np.nan])
2
```

---

```
print (s1.loc[None])
2
```

EDIT1:

For stripping whitespaces:

```
s = pd.Series(['90300', '90300', '8825', '8825', '8825', 'None ', np.nan])
print (s)
0    90300
1    90300
2     8825
3     8825
4     8825
5    None 
6      NaN
dtype: object

s1 = s.value_counts()
print (s1)
8825     3
90300    2
None     1
dtype: int64

s1.index = s1.index.str.strip()
print (s1.loc['None'])
1
```

Comment: That didn't work  >>> df.loc[df.index.isin([None])]
Series([], Name: product_code, dtype: int64)

Comment: Ok, what return `print (df.index)` ?

Comment: It's 31112 rows so it only prints the first and last 10 values (which doesn't include 'None'.

Comment: I think I found out the problem.  count_values() counts None as a NaN when counting, so the value for those fields in the resulting series is NaN, not None.

Comment: And values are not dropped?

Comment: I added the "dropna=False" option to values_count(), actually using values_count(dropna=False)

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things

1. `pd.Series([None] * 2 + [1] * 3).value_counts()` automatically drops the `None`.
2. `pd.Series([None] * 2 + [1] * 3).value_counts(dropna=False)` converts the `None` to `np.NaN`

That tells me that your `None` is a string.  But since `df.loc['None']` didn't work, I suspect your string has white space around it.

Try:

```
df.filter(regex='None', axis=0)
```

Or:

```
df.index = df.index.to_series().str.strip().combine_first(df.index.to_series())
df.loc['None']
```

---

All that said, I was curious how to reference `np.NaN` in the index

```
s = pd.Series([1, 2], [0, np.nan])
s.iloc[s.index.get_loc(np.nan)]

2
```